# SpringAOP AspectJ Initialized super.instance variable found to be null NPE

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop

Am trying to integrate Aspects to old monolithic Spring MVC application configured via XML schema. 
Spring AOP is configured via `<context:component-scan .../> & <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>`
The delegate bean schema definition & the AOP config. has been placed in same schema context definition file.

The instance variable handing out NPE is declared in Parent abstract class of the delegate, its of modifier Protected accessor default

Aspect advice applied is @Before, `@Before("execution(* c.x.at.movement.webservice.WsVerifyTxn.process(..) )")`, and simple log statement inside advice.

Without SpringAOP AspectJ, disabled, am able to execute the flow without any erroring scenario.

No place super.variable has been assigned to null.

Would be very much thankful if anyone could direct or suggest to get me out of this distress!

Below are three stack traces for review

### 1 >> Error stack trace

```
c.x.a.c.transaction.PersistableTxn.retrieveData(@664): Error executing Business Delegate Controller for uri '/snippet/verify': 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at c.x.a.c.transaction.PersistableTxn.retrieveData(PersistableTxn.java:664)
    at c.x.a.c.transaction.PersistableTxn.getTxnHistory(PersistableTxn.java:891)
    at c.x.a.c.transaction.PersistableTxn.finalize(PersistableTxn.java:562)
    at c.x.at.movement.BaseDelegate.finalize(BaseDelegate.java:257)
    at c.x.at.movement.BaseDelegate$$FastClassByCGLIB$$cbb13d00_2.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at c.x.at.movement.webservice.WsVerifyTxn$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$5ee08d0e.finalize(<generated>)
    at c.x.a.c.businessdelegate.PersistableBusinessDelegate.postProcess(PersistableBusinessDelegate.java:118)
    at c.x.a.c.businessdelegate.BusinessDelegateAdapter.execute(BusinessDelegateAdapter.java:297)
    at c.x.a.c.businessdelegate.spring.BusinessDelegateController.handleRequestInternal(BusinessDelegateController.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at c.x.commons.session.servlet.SSMCFilter.doFilter(SSMCFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at c.x.commons.security.auth.xAuthFilter$_filter_action.run(xAuthFilter.java:78)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
    at c.x.commons.util.j2ee.J2EESubjectPropagaterNoOp.doAsPrivileged(J2EESubject.java:80)
    at c.x.commons.security.auth.xAuthFilter.doFilter(xAuthFilter.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at c.x.commons.cs203.servlet.CS203CoreServletFilter.doFilter(CS203CoreServletFilter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at c.x.a.c.model.accountinfo.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

### 2 >> Debug stack trace in flow step 1, the variable has been initialized

```
Daemon Thread [http-bio-9080-exec-2] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 196 in BusinessDelegate))   
    owns: SocketWrapper<E>  (id=363)    
    WsVerifyTxn$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$eeedc57b(BusinessDelegate).preProcess(xContext, Object) line: 196 
    WsVerifyTxn$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$eeedc57b(PersistableBusinessDelegate).preProcess(xContext, Object) line: 34   
    BusinessDelegateAdapter.execute(RequestContext) line: 267   
    BusinessDelegateController.handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 175 
    BusinessDelegateController(AbstractController).handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 153 
    SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Object) line: 48 
    DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 790 
    DispatcherServlet.doService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 719  
    DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).processRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 644   
    DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 560   
    DispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 646   
    DispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 727   
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 303  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    WsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 52    
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    SSMCFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 79  
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    xAuthFilter$_filter_action.run() line: 78   
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
    Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject, PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: 536   
    J2EESubjectPropagaterNoOp.doAsPrivileged(Subject, PrivilegedExceptionAction, AccessControlContext) line: 80 
    xAuthFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 154    
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    CS203CoreServletFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 86  
    DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(Filter, ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 237    
    DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 167  
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    CacheFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 53 
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 220    
    StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 122    
    NonLoginAuthenticator(AuthenticatorBase).invoke(Request, Response) line: 503    
    StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 170   
    ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 103    
    AccessLogValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 950  
    StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 116 
    CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 421  
    Http11Processor(AbstractHttp11Processor<S>).process(SocketWrapper<S>) line: 1070    
    Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler(AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler<S,P>).process(SocketWrapper<S>, SocketStatus) line: 611   
    JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() line: 314 
    ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1110  
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 603   
    TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() line: 61  
    TaskThread(Thread).run() line: 722
```

### 3 >> Debug stack trace in flow, step 2, before the statement exectuion where NPE would be thrown

```
Daemon Thread [http-bio-9080-exec-2] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 664 in PersistableTxn)) 
    owns: SocketWrapper<E>  (id=363)    
    WsVerifyTxn(PersistableTxn).retrieveData(String) line: 664  
    WsVerifyTxn(PersistableTxn).getTxnHistory() line: 891   
    WsVerifyTxn(PersistableTxn).finalize(Persistable, xContext, xModelOutput) line: 562 
    WsVerifyTxn(BaseDelegate).finalize(Persistable, xContext, xModelOutput) line: 257   
    BaseDelegate$$FastClassByCGLIB$$cbb13d00_2.invoke(int, Object, Object[]) line: not available    
    MethodProxy.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 191  
    Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint() line: 688    
    Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 150    
    ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(MethodInvocation) line: 89   
    Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation(ReflectiveMethodInvocation).proceed() line: 172    
    Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Object, Method, Object[], MethodProxy) line: 621 
    WsVerifyTxn$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$eeedc57b.finalize(Persistable, xContext, xModelOutput) line: not available    
    WsVerifyTxn$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$eeedc57b(PersistableBusinessDelegate).postProcess(xContext, xModelOutput) line: 118   
    BusinessDelegateAdapter.execute(RequestContext) line: 297   
    BusinessDelegateController.handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 175 
    BusinessDelegateController(AbstractController).handleRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 153 
    SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, Object) line: 48 
    DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 790 
    DispatcherServlet.doService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 719  
    DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).processRequest(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 644   
    DispatcherServlet(FrameworkServlet).doPost(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 560   
    DispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) line: 646   
    DispatcherServlet(HttpServlet).service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 727   
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 303  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    WsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 52    
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    SSMCFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 79  
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    xAuthFilter$_filter_action.run() line: 78   
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]   
    Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject, PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext) line: 536   
    J2EESubjectPropagaterNoOp.doAsPrivileged(Subject, PrivilegedExceptionAction, AccessControlContext) line: 80 
    xAuthFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 154    
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    CS203CoreServletFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 86  
    DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(Filter, ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 237    
    DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 167  
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    CacheFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 53 
    ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 241  
    ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 208  
    StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 220    
    StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 122    
    NonLoginAuthenticator(AuthenticatorBase).invoke(Request, Response) line: 503    
    StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 170   
    ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 103    
    AccessLogValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 950  
    StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 116 
    CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 421  
    Http11Processor(AbstractHttp11Processor<S>).process(SocketWrapper<S>) line: 1070    
    Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler(AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler<S,P>).process(SocketWrapper<S>, SocketStatus) line: 611   
    JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() line: 314 
    ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor).runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1110  
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 603   
    TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() line: 61  
    TaskThread(Thread).run() line: 722
```